# multiple WSS installations on a server each targetting a different subdomain?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Is it possible to have multiple WSS installations on a server each targeting a different sub domain?

For instance, if i have a domain foo.bar.com and have one WSS installation for that, how can i have another WSS installation for foo2.bar.com?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need multiple WSS installations for this purpose. You can create multiple web applications and assign appropriate host header in IIS for this.

Answer (score 1):

Madhar is correct.  Furthermore, a server can only be a part of a single SharePoint Farm i.e. single wss installations.